# How to debug error "NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFound Exception" coming at runtime?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I am using Intellij. My java application has a dependency on an external jar. I have added the jar using below steps:

- File > Project Structure > libraries > "+" > added .jar path

I have added the dependencies to this external jar as below:

- File > Project Structure > Modules > dependencies tab > "+" > added .jar

I am able to successfully build the app using classes from external jar but getting ClassNoFoundException at runtime for the class existing in external jar.

Please help me debug this error.

P.S. -> I am quite new to Java and Intellij.